# Extra grey panel on the right

Tags: css

I am getting an extra grey "panel" on the right hand side of my website if you make the size of the page smaller than 997px. It gets bigger as the page size decreases.

[image: extra grey "panel" on the right hand side]

[*Here*](http://www.dwcworld.com/home) is my site. Please can someone help?

Comment: See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can't reproduce it on your site anyway.

Comment: It happens on Chrome and Firefox. When the browser is smaller than 997px, a scroll bar becomes visible at the bottom of the screen. I can't give "minimal coding" as there are 6400 files for the site.

Comment: Can't reproduce it in Chrome, and *I'm* not going to check 6400 files to find a problem that I can't even reproduce. The mcve is to isolate the problem too. Most of the time you will find the solution yourself, and otherwise you will at least have an isolated situation in which we may be able to spot the issue. If you don't know where to look in these 6400 files, how have you buit this website in the first place?

Comment: Thanx. I didn't build it, I just have to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the PHP notices are causing the problems here. I can't really replicate the issue without reducing the size of the browser to below 500px then scrolling to the right. This tells me that it's an overflow issue and the grey panel is simply the background.

Take a look through your HTML to find any elements that might be exceeding the maximum width of the main content.

Comment: @Damian The problem is caused by the `wf-table` at the `bottom-bar`. If you add `#bottom-bar .wf-td { display: block; }`, the gray side will disappear.

Comment: Agreed @Damian, this fixed it on mine

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code of [the main page](http://www.dwcworld.com/home). And I found:

1. strange patchwork instead of `<head>` and `<body>`
2. several fragments like this

```html
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: ver</p>
<p>Filename: template/template_assets_css.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 7</p>
```

Therefore, please check your PHP-files, before you start setting up styles.

**Update**

Now the HTML-code looks correct, and error messages are commented out. Something had changed or I have viewed wrong, I don't know.